# mssparkutils.notebook.exit in Try block

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-notebooks

`mssparkutils.notebook.exit` isn't exiting properly when used in try block, and it is rising exception. Can someone help me understand, why it isn't working inside try block? and how to make it work?

[image]
[image]

it worked, if not using try block.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when I am executing `mssparkutils.notebook.exit(Id)` with `try` `except` block of code:

```
import logging
import traceback
try:
  if True:  
    df = spark.createDataFrame(
        [
                (1, "AA"), 
                (2, "BB"),
        ],
        ["id", "Name"] 
    )
    Id = df.select('id').rdd.map(lambda x: x[0]).first()

    mssparkutils.notebook.exit(Id)

except:
   logging.error(traceback.format_exc())
```

I got the same output:

[image]

In above code snippet If an exception is raised within the `try` block, the `except` block executes, and the traceback of the exception is logged using the `logging.error()` function. However, after catching the exception, the code continues executing the rest of the program, and the traceback is displayed as the output.

As per this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/microsoft-spark-utilities?pivots=programming-language-python) When you call an `exit()` function from a notebook interactively, Azure Synapse will throw an exception, that may be the reason it is going to exception block and giving the output as above.

Due to exception, it is giving null as exit value while executing the notebook activity. If you want to get exit value with, try-except block then call exit value in except block as mentioned below:

```
import logging
import traceback
try:
  if True:  
    df = spark.createDataFrame(
        [
                (1, "AA"), 
                (2, "BB"),
        ],
        ["id", "Name"] 
    )
    Id = df.select('id').rdd.map(lambda x: x[0]).first()

    mssparkutils.notebook.exit(Id)

except:
   logging.error(traceback.format_exc())
   mssparkutils.notebook.exit(Id)
```

You will get the exit value as mentioned below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but the notebook will be treated as failed, isn't it? @Bhavani

Comment: Yes, the notebook is considered "failed" because an exception was raised, but it is not a typical failure. It's better to execute notebook without try-except block.

Comment: Which I understand, to make this work, it has to be without try except, But the point, is, it shouldn't through exception.